# Поиск руткитов средствами rkhunter

Tags: unix, rkhunter

Запустил на сервере *rkhunter*. Все чисто, но вот одна строка в секции

> **Performing malware checks**

меня смущает:

> Checking running processes for suspicious files          [ Skipped ]

Что это может означать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А вы смотрели в лог /var/log/rkhunter.log ? Нет ли там каких-нибудь ошибок? Например, такой:

> [11:42:10] Info: Unable to find the 'lsof' command

Вообще, к сожалению, это может означать что угодно. Во время проверки произошла какая-то ошибка и без дополнительных сведений её не обнаружить..

Comment: Да, все верно. Сам ступил. Надо было посмотреть логи, прежде чем задавать вопрос.
lsof не был установлен в системе.
[12:57:21] Info: Starting test name 'running_procs'
[12:57:21]   Checking running processes for suspicious files [ Skipped ]
[12:57:21] Info: Unable to find the 'lsof' command